# Error with the workflow on GitHub when I publish my quarto website

Tags: github-actions, quarto

I want to publish my Quarto HTML as a website on GitHub. It works, but I have an error and so the red cross. I have this in my workflow:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: main

name: Quarto Publish

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2

      - name: Install Python and Dependencies
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          cache: 'pip'
      - run: pip install jupyter
      - run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Render and Publish
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/publish@v2
        with:
          target: gh-pages
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

and I have this error:

`ERROR: The specified path (.) is not a website or book project so cannot be published.`

My file isn't in the main directory on GitHub. It's in a sub-directory. I don't know if it's important or not but I think that's the issue and I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to do it again but there was the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide the correct path to the `publish` action (see [*Other configurations*](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-actions/tree/main/publish#other-configurations)):

```yaml
      - name: Render and Publish
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/publish@v2
        with:
          target: gh-pages
          path: path/to/your/directory
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Thank you I don't have this error anymore (I have an other one now.. aha)